# Angular 4 Event emitters emitted events not receiving on page refreshing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, eventemitter

Hi I have a strange problem.The event emitters are not working properly for page refreshes.

First page is login page.After login navigates to home page.
I need the data to be displayed on header.component.html from home.component.ts

My components are as follows

**app.component.html**

```
<app-layout-header></app-layout-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-layout-footer></app-layout-footer>
```

**header.components.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-layout-header",
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: "./header.component.html"
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  profile = {};

  constructor(
    private _authService: AuthService,
    private _clipboardService: ClipboardService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._clipboardService.myProfileDataEvent.subscribe(data => {
      this.profile = data;
      console.log("data changes");
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component is destroyed
    this._clipboardService.myProfileDataEvent.unsubscribe();
  }

  logout() {
    this._authService.logout();
  }
}
```

**clipboard.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ClipboardService {
  @Output() myProfileDataEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {
    this.myProfileDataEvent.emit({Name:'Siraj'})
  }

  setProfileData(data: any) {
    console.log("emitting events");
    return this.myProfileDataEvent.emit(data);
  }

}
```

On home.component.ts I am calling an api and updating the profile data by calling

```
this._clipboardService.setProfileData(response.json().payload.Profile)
```

**home.component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this._authService.checkLogin();
    this._profileService.getHomeData()
      .subscribe(response => {
       this._clipboardService.setProfileData(response.json().payload.Profile)
        },
        err => {
          alert('home data error');
        });
  }
```

It is working if I come to home page after login operation.But after login if I refresh the page emitted event is not received on header.component.ts

Can somebody help me plz.

Comment: "On home.component.ts I am calling an api and updating the profile data by calling `this._clipboardService.setProfileData(response.json().payload.Profile)`" -- where?

Comment: @  Lazar Ljubenović  for route '/' under home.component.ts

Comment: You're not sowing enough code. Create a reproduction on Plunker or StackBlitz.

Comment: @ Lazar Ljubenović  I edited question.Added home.component.ts code

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view the onInit method of HeaderComponent is too late after I tested it on constructor it works. It seems the Subscription of Event Emitter must be done before OnInit.

I tried to reconstruct your code, but it wasn't easy.

[Working Online Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewa45g)

Comment: Following is the order of logs  cb service constructor, header constructor, header init, home ng init